# How to rewrite grep call from Linux to AIX

Tags: grep, portability

In my Linux system in `fgrep` I am using atributes `-m 500 -C 0`. But on AIX I didnt see these arguments. So how should I rewrite it? I just read to use awk instead of fgrep but I don't know how.

Comment: what other args to fgrep are used?

Answer (score 3):

The two options you mentioned are specific to GNU grep.

- `-m 500` -- stop reading after the first 500 matching lines
- `-C 0` -- print zero lines of output context

The behavior with `-C 0` is already the default behavior, so there's nothing special needed to emulate it on AIX. All you need to worry about is how to limit output to the first 500 matches. One way to do this would be to pipe the output from `fgrep` through `head`:

```
fgrep [options...] [files...] | head -n500
```

If you need to use `-C` with some other number, you are correct that you will probably need to script it with something like `awk`, since AIX `grep` doesn't have this capability. A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685678/advanced-grep-unix) asked over on Stack Overflow that has several answers you may find helpful.

Comment: a side-effect of `-C 0` is that it prints a group divider "--" between separate groups of matched lines. Try: `echo -e 'a\nb\na\nb'|fgrep -C 0 a`.

Comment: thx for answer but I mention argument -C because I need to use it like -C 5. In link which you add is just mention when I am looking for one file but not on files with patter like log-*-app.log

Answer (score 1):

The man page for `fgrep` explains `-m 500` as meaning "stop after matching 500 lines". The `-C 0` shows no lines of context, which is the default.

Without being able to see how you're calling `fgrep` I would suggest that this could be one approximation:

```
fgrep ... | head -500
```

Answer (score 1):

This bash/awk script will emulate some limited cases of grep `-C` and `-m`.
You should edit it till it matches your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash
# emulate grep -m <number> -C <number> <pattern> <file>... with awk. 

context=0
todo=999999
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do  case $1 in
        -m) shift
            todo=$1 ;;
        -C) shift
            context=$1 ;;
        -*) echo "unsupported: $1" >&2
            exit 1 ;;
        *)  break ;;
        esac
        shift
done
pattern=${1?missing pattern}
shift

awk -v context="$context" -v pat="$pattern" -v todo="$todo" '
BEGIN{ held = -1 }
{ for(i = context;i>0;i--)lb[i] = lb[i-1];
  lb[0] = sprintf("%s:%d:%s",FILENAME,NR,$0);
  held++;
}
$0 ~ pat && done++<todo {
 if(held>context){
        if(done!=1)print "--";
        held = context;
 }
 for(i = held;i>0;i--)print lb[i];
 held = -1;
 max = NR+context;
}
NR<=max { print lb[0]; held = -1 }
' "$@"
```